# How to wrap multiple div without changing inner div posittion

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

So I'm having this issue, I'm coding a basic website using NextJS, this is an example of my code

I have a set of div like this with **relative** positioning

```
<div>one</div>
<div>two</div>
<div>three</div>
```

output it looks something like this

```
one two three
```

Now I want to wrap all 3 divs inside another div with **absolute** positioning so I can change its position freely across the screen

```
<div>
  <div>one</div>
  <div>two</div>
  <div>three</div>
</div>
```

But doing that will change inner div layout to this

```
one
two
three
```

So basically, how do I wrap multiple divs inside another div without changing inner div position?

Comment: Why not use flexbox?  https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: `position:relative` by itself wouldn't put the `<div>`s on the same line, it has to be caused by something else, but it's hard to say without an actual working code snippet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in your CSS code for the **inner** divs:

```
display: inline-block;
```

and this for the **outer** div:

```
width: fit-content;
```

See [this jsfiddle demonstration](https://jsfiddle.net/wqfgdj2u/)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```css
.parent{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
}

.child{
  display: inline-block
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">One</div>
  <div class="child">Two</div>
  <div class="child">Three</div>
</div>
```